# Cordova app android debug in chrome

Tags: android, cordova, debugging

Debugging application does not work in chrome.

The phone is displayed in the panel chrome, and the application does not.
On the phone, the application is launched. But I can not debug it.

[Panel chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf7rF.jpg)
[Cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yrMx.jpg)

Comment: Have you activated the USB-debug-mode of your phone? On Lollipop: Settings -> Developeroptions -> USB-Debugging  You might dusconnect and connect your phone again in order to see your app in the chrome-panel. This [link](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm) might help you.

Comment: @Blauharley, yes activated.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem, your APK-File is not really built (Skipping built), but another apk is taken instead (Using apk: ...... ). So that's why your computer can not establish a debug-connection to your app. What command have you entered in your shell? I run this: cordova run android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure browser platform is added to the app.
Launch your application's web browser.
Open Chrome and point to the application (IPaddress:port).
Go to Settings->More Tools->Developer Options or just press Ctrl+Shift+I if you are on Windows.
Click on **Console**. This should show you the app's console output.

If you want the console for the phone app, try using something like [PhoneGap Desktop](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/). There are many other ways, of course.